# iOS how to implement tabs in a web browser

Tags: ios, uiwebview, tabs, browser

I'm making a web browser and I am completely at a loss at how to implement tabs. Can someone point me in the direction of a tutorial or would be willing to make some sort of tutorial for me, or at least tell me what needs to be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an in app web browser that uses tabs. This web browser is a pop up web browser that supports all orientation and all iOS devices. Check it here: http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/397/ZWebBrowser/